# NodeJS Express running on AWS Lambda returns error: 'listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use'

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've set up `AWS lambda` with some `NodeJS` code to learn creating an API. API is set up using `Express`. The runtime is `v18`. I also set up `API Gateway` HTTP API with the `lambda` integration to invoke it.

When I try to call `GET` method on the `/collage` route I get `internal server error` and the Lambda logs return the following:

```
ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use /tmp/server-undefined.sock",
    "code": "EADDRINUSE",
    "errno": -98,
    "syscall": "listen",
    "address": "/tmp/server-undefined.sock",
    "port": -1,
    "stack": [
        "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use /tmp/server-undefined.sock",
        "    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1468:21)",
        "    at listenInCluster (node:net:1533:12)",
        "    at Server.listen (node:net:1632:5)",
        "    at Function.listen (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)",
        "    at startServer (/var/task/node_modules/@vendia/serverless-express/src/index.js:138:17)",
        "    at proxy (/var/task/node_modules/@vendia/serverless-express/src/index.js:191:14)",
        "    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/@vendia/serverless-express/src/index.js:192:32)",
        "    at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)",
        "    at emitListeningNT (node:net:1519:10)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)"
    ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const { proxy } = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = express();

app.get('/collage', (req, res) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello, World!' })
  };
  return response;
});

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  return proxy(app, event, context);
};
```

The code is as basic as it gets and I put it ogether using some example tutorials and GPT3. Not really sure what could be the issue or how to debug it. There should be no port conflicts since it runs in Lambda..

I did accidentaly include `app.listen(3000, () =>{});` before when I deployed the initial version. But it has since been fixed and lambda re-deployed. To make sure I even created a new lambda and deployed latest version to it and got same error.

I tried searching this error on the web, but everyone recommends killing the process, but this is running in `lambda` so not really possible.

What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a deprecated package `aws-serverless-express`.

You should use [serverless-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-express)

> On 11/30, the AWS Serverless Express library is moving to Vendia and will be rebranded to serverless-express. Similarly, the aws-serverless-express NPM package will be deprecated in favor of a new serverless-express package.

Comment: Hmm okay, will look into the rebranded library. I suppose even though it's deprecated it should still work, but hopefully the other library fixes my issue. Thanks

Comment: @robliv did the new library resolve your issue?